# Decomposition random variable with conditional expectation

Tags: random-variable, decomposition

Why given some information set $I$, any random variable $x_t$ can be decomposed into the sum:

$$x_t = E(x_t | I) + v_t $$
where $E(v_t | I) = 0$.

I'm looking for a clear proof.

Comment: Would not work for Cauchy distribution.